# How to parse CSV file with string objectkeys instead of "raw" strings?

Tags: javascript, excel, csv, encoding

I tried parsing a CSV file in Javascript and I got the following results:

```
[ 
  {
    'Title': 'Random Brand 1',
    'Brand Code': '5205',
    Display: 'Brand'
  },
  {
    'Title': 'Random Brand 2',
    'Brand Code': '5201',
    Display: 'Sponsorship'
  },
  {
    'Title': 'Random Brand 3',
    'Brand Code': '5203',
    Display: 'Both'
  }
]
```

The "Title" keys are wrapped in quotes, but Display does not. "Brand Code" is in quotes which is fine because it's two words. How do I parse it so that Title will be like Display and has not quotes? Something like this:

```
  {
    Title: 'Random Brand 3',
    'Brand Code': '5203',
    Display: 'Both'
  }
```

I am parsing the file like this:

```
import csvParse from 'csv-parse/lib/sync'
const brands = csvParse(fs.readFileSync(csv), { columns: true })
```

Do I have to change something on Excel?

Comment: How are you parsing the CSV in JavaScript? You haven't shown us any actual code.

Comment: Your objects are all valid JS object literals (JS does not require enquoted keys, only JSON does). If you want to generate valid JSON (with enquoted keys) then pass your objects into `JSON.stringify`. JavaScript objects in-memory have keys that are always keys anyway, so you cannot add quotes to keys to in-memory objects for the same way that you can't reorder keyed elements of objects either (i.e. it's a JS engine internal detail).

Comment: @Dai Sorry, I edited my question to include that

Comment: @Dai Right, they are all valid in JS. But I have to follow to linting rule which automatically changes one word key from brands['Title'] to brands.Title. And Title is in quotes, brands.Title returns undefined.

Comment: A linter will only complain about `.js` and `.json` files located in your project's filesystem; it cannot be complaining about JS objects you're creating at runtime (that's philosophically impossible...), so what's going on? If your project is generating those JS objects at runtime but saving them into your project's filesystem then you should save them to a folder that is excluded from your Linter or to a directory located outside of your project's root.